# InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input to reshape is a tensor with 35000 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 7500

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensor

I'm using this code for a convolutional neural network.

```
learning_rate = 0.001
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 50*50]) 
X_img = tf.reshape(X, [-1, 50, 50, 3])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 26])

W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 3, 32]))
L1 = tf.nn.conv2d(X_img, W1, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
L1 = tf.nn.relu(L1)
L1 = tf.nn.max_pool(L1, ksize=[1, 5, 5, 1], strides=[1, 5, 5, 1], padding='SAME') 

W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 32, 64]))
L2 = tf.nn.conv2d(L1, W2, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
L2 = tf.nn.relu(L2)
L2 = tf.nn.max_pool(L2, ksize=[1, 5, 5, 1], strides=[1, 5, 5, 1], padding='SAME')

L2_flat = tf.reshape(L2, [-1, 5*5*64])
W3 = tf.get_variable("W3", shape=[5*5*64, 26], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
print(W3)
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([26]))
logits = tf.matmul(L2_flat, W3) + b

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=Y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

training_epochs = 15
batch_size = 14
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print('Learning started. It takes sometime.')
for epoch in range(training_epochs):
    avg_cost = 0
    total_batch = int(len(train_input) / batch_size)

    for i in range(total_batch):
        start = ((i+1) * batch_size) - batch_size
        end = ((i+1) * batch_size)
        batch_xs = train_input[start:end]
        batch_ys = train_label[start:end]
        feed_dict = {X: batch_xs, Y: batch_ys}
        c, _ = sess.run([cost, optimizer], feed_dict=feed_dict)
        avg_cost += c / total_batch
    print('Epoch:', '%04d' % (epoch +1), 'cost = ', '{:.9f}'.format(avg_cost))
print('Learning Finished')
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print('Accuracy:', sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={
      X: test_input, Y: test_label}))
```

I'm reading 50x50 RGB images. I have 406 pictures and 26 labels.
I'm using 5x5 filter and my train inputs shape appear 
`print(train_input.shape)` `(1218, 2500)`
I don't understand why '1218' appear and what this number mean.
And also don't understand the following errors.

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1321     try:
-> 1322       return fn(*args)
   1323     except errors.OpError as e:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1306       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(
-> 1307           options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1308 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1408           self._session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1409           run_metadata)
   1410     else:

InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 35000 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 7500
     [[Node: Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_Placeholder_0_0, Reshape/shape)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-e97c33c78b58> in <module>()
     16         batch_ys = train_label[start:end]
     17         feed_dict = {X: batch_xs, Y: batch_ys}
---> 18         c, _ = sess.run([cost, optimizer], feed_dict=feed_dict)
     19         avg_cost += c / total_batch
     20     print('Epoch:', '%04d' % (epoch +1), 'cost = ', '{:.9f}'.format(avg_cost))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    898     try:
    899       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 900                          run_metadata_ptr)
    901       if run_metadata:
    902         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1133     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1134       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1135                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1136     else:
   1137       results = []

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1314     if handle is None:
   1315       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
-> 1316                            run_metadata)
   1317     else:
   1318       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1333         except KeyError:
   1334           pass
-> 1335       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1336 
   1337   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 35000 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 7500
     [[Node: Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_Placeholder_0_0, Reshape/shape)]]

Caused by op 'Reshape', defined at:
  File "C:\Users\sunghee hong\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\sunghee hong\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\sunghee hong\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "C:\Users\sunghee hong\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "C:\Users\sunghee hong\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 486, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "C:\Users\sunghee hong\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 127, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\sunghee hong\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 422, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Users\sunghee hong\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1432, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "C:\Users\sunghee hong\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 145, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "C:\Users\sunghee hong\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 117, in _handle_events
    handler_func(fileobj, events)
  File "C:\Users\sunghee hong\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 276, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sunghee hong\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 450, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "C:\Users\sunghee hong\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 480, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "C:\Users\sunghee hong\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 432, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sunghee hong\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 276, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sunghee hong\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "C:\Users\sunghee hong\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "C:\Users\sunghee hong\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "C:\Users\sunghee hong\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "C:\Users\sunghee hong\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sunghee hong\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2662, in run_cell
    raw_cell, store_history, silent, shell_futures)
  File "C:\Users\sunghee hong\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2785, in _run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "C:\Users\sunghee hong\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2903, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "C:\Users\sunghee hong\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2963, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-11-02a422681da1>", line 4, in <module>
    X_img = tf.reshape(X, [-1, 50, 50, 3]) #[batch, width, height, image channel(RGB:3, GRAY:1)], batch size는 가변할 수 있어서 대부분 -1
  File "C:\Users\sunghee hong\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 6112, in reshape
    "Reshape", tensor=tensor, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\sunghee hong\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\sunghee hong\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3392, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\sunghee hong\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1718, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input to reshape is a tensor with 35000 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 7500
     [[Node: Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_Placeholder_0_0, Reshape/shape)]]



​
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question 1.

**print(train_input.shape) (1218, 2500)**

The `1218` value comes from `X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 50*50])` and you are feeding in 406 50x50 RGB images(3 channels).

Or in other words, by this line of code, you are requesting input tensor of size `[406, 3, 50, 50] -> [?, 2500]`. So you get `1218 = 406*3`.

Your question 2.
It's kind of weird for your input tensor to have `35000` values, please have another check around the line `X_img = tf.reshape(X, [-1, 50, 50, 3])` for the size of `X`